# How do I programmatically detect deleted WhatsApp messages?

Tags: android, whatsapp, notification-listener

I'm creating an app for detecting deleted WhatsApp Messages.

I used a **notification listener** to detect messages from WhatsApp.

But it detects all notification messages from WhatsApp, while **I want to detect only the deleted message.**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a message inside WhatsApp does not post a notification. Thus the answer to your question is, it's impossible to do with a NotificationListener

Comment: When the message was deleted, the notification will occur, i have tested that.  The App called "WhatsRemoved" available in play store, which detects the deleted messages perfectly. i didnt know the logic.

Comment: This raises the question, why do you need to clone the app? But a notification is what shows in the status bar. Maybe there is some confusion in terminology here

Comment: I'm trying to add some more features, i'm not trying to clone the app.

Comment: @Tim Any luck ?